# Pass arguments from nodejs to python script using python-shell

Tags: python, node.js

I'm trying to run a python script inside a Nodejs project. Everything works pretty well passing a local video URL in my python script, but I need to retrieve the video URL from my MongoDB and pass it to the python script. Is there a way I can do this? I have made some research and couldn't find a way to solve this issue.

```
app.get('/test', callName); 
  
function callName(req, res) { 
  PythonShell.run('ai_part/test.py', null, function (err) {  
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('finished');
  });
}
```

Python code:

```
#Loading the video input
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.wmv')

_, img = cap.read()
height, width, _ = img.shape
copy = img.copy()
```

I don't know if it is clear enough, but I need to pass a video URL acquired from my mongo database into the python function 'VideoCapture(url)'. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Like [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/python-shell#running-a-python-script-with-arguments-and-options) tells you,

```
function callName(req, res) {
  let options = {
    mode: 'text',
    args: [res]
  };
  PythonShell.run('ai_part/test.py', options, function (err) {  
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('finished');
  });
}
```